# Sorting a lot of data efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, sorting

I am using C# to sort a lot of objects (few million sets) according to 2 parameters.

Each set of data has should be grouped together if they have the same 2 parameters. I used to use 2 for loops to sort this data but with functions and sorting the data one by one is just too slow.

Example data set

```
Obj[i].type= bag;
Obj[i].colour= blue;
```

All the other data that has both bag and blue should be sorted together.

What I have also tried was to use something like this, but this only gets one unique parameter.

```
var uniquetype= new HashSet<string>(Obj.type);
```

I would still need to loop through each one of them in another loop to sort out the data again. I was thinking if it is possible to sort 2 parameters at once quickly to reduce computation time. or maybe sort it out in an array form by appending the index of the objects as a string e.g. `array[i] += Obj.Parameter1.ToString()`.

By using this method, it will only loop through once to get all the index values of objects with similar parameters. If I need a particular object, I would slice the string of numbers and create another loop `Obj[numFromArray[i]]`.

Is there a sorting method out there that I can explore?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use value tuples in your hash set `HashSet<(string Type, string Colour)>`

Comment: Why not just do `Obj.OrderBy(x => x.type).ThenBy(x => x.colour)` or maybe `Obj.OrderBy(x => (x.type, x.colour))`?

Comment: When you say *"should be grouped together if they have the same 2 parameters"* you mean to be positioned in adjacent positions in the resulting array, or to be literally grouped in subarrays?

Comment: Oh thank you Juharr, using thenby solved my problem